# "which groups such as 3.14 Action"

Tags: meaning, relative-pronouns

> I hope that many scientists (and others with an appreciation of
> science) will seek appointment to zoning boards or run for state,
> county or local political office, **which groups such as 3.14 Action**,
> based in Washington DC, train scientists to do. Otherwise, developers
> will be free to destroy wetlands without heeding the benefits they
> provide to people and nature.
> [Source: Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-01827-y)

Does "which" here mean "the thing or fact that"?

Comment: It helped. Please make your reply an answer which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cited example, ***which*** refers back to the verb phrase ***seek appointment to zoning boards or run for state, county or local political office***.

To help "deconstruct" the text, start by discarding the optional second part of that long verb phrase (from ***or*** onwards). Also discard the optional reference to the location where 3.14 are based. A bit of resequencing then gives us...

> ***Groups such as 3.14 Action train scientists to seek appointment to zoning boards.***

Compare *I hope you get a job, **which** I can help you to do*, which is structurally the same as OP's example (***which*** refers back to the preceding verb phrase ***get a job***). We can resequence in the same way to get rid of ***which***...

> *I hope you get a job, **which** I can help you to do*
> ...
> ***I can help you get a job***